# SourceTree ошибка входа в учетную запись Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, source-tree

При попытке склонировать репозиторий вылазит такая ошибка:

> Ошибка входа в учётную запись Bitbucket.
>
> Ответ сервера: «Ссылка на необъявленный объект подстановки "mdash", строка 5, позиция 32.»

Подскажите, в чем косяк?

Comment: Абсолютна такая же ошибка вылезает на свежеустановленной Source Tree, видимо баг в клиенте, будем ждать патча.

Comment: Вы используете пароль для входа в битбакет, или пароль для приложений, сгенерированный вот здесь: https://bitbucket.org/account/user/gambala/app-passwords ?